# How to add link in to array value ?

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, moodle

is there any simple way to create new array with extra value ?

```
$table->data = array(
    array('Harry Potter', '76%', 'Getting better'),
    array('Rincewind', '89%', 'Lucky as usual'),
    array('Elminster Aumar', '100%', 'Easy when you know everything!')
);
```

**Result expecting like this**

```
$table->data = array(
    array('Harry Potter', '76%', 'Getting better', '<a href="more.php">View</a>'),
    array('Rincewind', '89%', 'Lucky as usual', '<a href="more.php">View</a>'),
    array('Elminster Aumar', '100%', 'Easy when you know everything!', '<a href="more.php">View</a>')
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($table->data as &$arr){
  array_push($arr, '<a href="more.php">View</a>');
}
```

Note the `&` prepended to `$arr`.  This tells the loop to use references for each iteration, instead of values.  That way, when the loop exits, your array will remain modified the way you would like.

To answer your comment, something like this would work

```
foreach($table->data as &$arr){
  $arr[0] = '<a href="more.php">' . $arr[0] . '</a>';
}
```

this assumes that the value you want to change will ALWAYS be the first element in the array.  If that is the case, then your set.  If not the answer will look similar but you will need an additional check.

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response. 
can I try this `print_r($table->data)` after `foreach` ?

Comment: sure you can try whatever you want

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't show any change when try this `print_r($table->data);`

Comment: only one array shows when try this `print_r($arr);`

Comment: sry, i forgot to make `$arr` a reference, see the updated answer, with the `&` prepended to `$arr` the loop will use references instead of values so the changes should stick after the loop

Comment: @eleriko one more question if you don't mind. Is it possible to show like this `array('<a href="more.php">Elminster Aumar</a>', '100%', 'Easy when you know everything!')`